# How to select all radiobuttons after buttonclick android

Tags: android

I am working on an application where I have multiple linear layouts which are dynamically generated. Each linearlayout has an Id field, Name and a radioGroup containing two radio buttons for Yes and No.

I am also providing a button at bottom of the page so that once the button is clicked, All the YES radio buttons are selected.

How can i achive this as the layout is dynamically generated based on some data:

Here is my layout which is repeated dynamically:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="10">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:id="@+id/RollNum"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:gravity="center">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Amandeep Singh and some very very long name"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/Name"
                        android:textSize="20dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:gravity="center">
                        <RadioGroup
                            android:id="@+id/radioAttendance"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation='horizontal'
                            android:gravity="center">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="P"
                            android:id="@+id/PresentCheck"
                            android:textSize="10dp"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            />
                            <RadioButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="A"
                                android:id="@+id/AbsentCheck"
                                android:textSize="15dp"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                />
                            </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1">
            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.1dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried following approach but didn't work:

```
    //some code before it for button clicks and all other stuffs

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout scrollViewLinearlayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent); // The layout inside scroll view
    //int count=50;
    Studentlist = Arrays.copyOfRange(StudentlistInterim, 1, StudentlistInterim.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < Studentlist.length; i++){
        String data = Studentlist[i];
        String RollNum = data.split("--")[0];
        String Name = data.split("--")[1];
        Log.d("Name is:", Name);

        LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(context);
        layout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null, false);

        layout2.addView(item);
        layout2.setId(i);
        TextView trollnum = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.RollNum);
        trollnum.setText(RollNum);
        TextView tname = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.Name);
        tname.setText(Name);
        RadioButton rPresent = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(R.id.PresentCheck);
        RadioButton rAbsent = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(R.id.AbsentCheck);
        rPresent.setId(i); //tried to set a unique Id for all YES
        rAbsent.setId(Studentlist.length+i); // to make the id unique for each YES and NO entry

        scrollViewLinearlayout.addView(layout2);


        Log.d("Id is: ", trollnum.getText().toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bMarkAllPresent:
            for (int i=0;i<Studentlist.length;i++){//iterate over the list for the radio buttons
                RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(i);
                RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioAttendance);
                rg.check(r1.getId()); /* get the id of radio button one by one and mark it checked*/
                //Log.d("Button check id:", (r1.getId()));
            }
            break;
```

I got 'java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton' error in the onClick() method

I am not sure if this approach will work or if this is the best approach.

Please help.

Edit-1:

After using the List way of doing it as per the answer.

```
        RadioButton rPresent = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(R.id.PresentCheck);
        RadioButton rAbsent = (RadioButton)item.findViewById(R.id.AbsentCheck);
        //rPresent.setId(i);
        //rAbsent.setId(Studentlist.length+i); // to make the id unique for each present and absent entry
        presentRadioList.add(rPresent); //getting null pointer here
        absentRadioList.add(rAbsent);
```

I am getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest keeping two `List<RadioButton>`s, one for the "yes" selections and one for the "no" selections. Then you can just iterate through the appropriate list.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh I leave the details as an exercise for the reader. Start by learning about the `List` interface and the `ArrayList` class.

Comment: Hi, I tried the way you described, but i am getting nullPointerException. I have pasted the code above in an edit. Please check and let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh Start by looking at the logcat to determine which line causes the error.

Comment: Hi, i am getting error while adding the radiobutton to the list.